# How rename steps on test log in Lambda test app automation

Tags: appium, appium-java, lambdatest

i want rename steps like "click element"
[steps on lambda test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zaD8.png)
i have this in code:

```
MobileElement login = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@index='1']");
            login.click();
```

i want rename to differentiate one from another

Comment: Can you describe what your problem is? In what respect is what happens different from what you expect?